# Working around errors in order of cells within a range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range

I have a function that goes through a calendar and sets Sunday and Saturday, based on their column number. I then set a range for one week (Sunday to Saturday).

My problem is, when the loop hits Saturday, the two cells in the range `set week` seem to have swapped position, thus selecting Saturday through Sunday.

How do I work around this?

```
For colNum = 4 To 100
    Set currentCell = .Cells(rowNum, colNum)
    Set otCell = currentCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    Set regCell = currentCell.Offset(-2, 0)

    If colNum Mod 7 = 4 Then
        sun = colNum
    End If

    If colNum Mod 7 = 3 Then
        sat = colNum
    End If

    Set week = .Range(.Cells(rowNum, sun), .Cells(rowNum, sat))
    week.Select
Next colNum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really tough to understand what you mean, honestly. However, let's hope that you are building some kind of a fancy calendar, which starts from the 5. column and you need to separate the weeks. E.g. something like this (in colors to be easier):

[image]

Your code should only do some kind of action (in your case selection, in my case coloring the range), when it has defined the latest day of the week (in our case Saturday). In every other case, it should continue looping. Thus, try this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim colNum  As Long
    Dim week    As Range
    Dim sun     As Long
    Dim sat     As Long

    Dim bColor  As Boolean

    For colNum = 4 To 100
        If colNum Mod 7 = 4 Then
            sun = colNum
        ElseIf colNum Mod 7 = 3 Then
            sat = colNum
            Set week = Range(Cells(1, sun), Cells(200, sat))
            bColor = Not bColor
            If bColor Then
                week.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                week.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        End If
    Next colNum
End Sub
```

Edit:

In order to make your code working, try this:

```
If sat-sun <> 1 Then
    Set week = .Range(.Cells(rowNum, sun), .Cells(rowNum, sat))
    week.Select
End If
```

Comment: You understood my question right. My problem is that after selecting the first week correctly, my function recognizes Saturday-Sunday as a week, and selects it. So in your example, after selecting the first week correctly(red), it would select the last column of red, and first column of green, instead of selecting green.

Comment: @jiwanheo - why don't you use my example? Anyway, see the edit.

Comment: I did in fact! Placing the Set week inside the ElseIf solved it. Thank you